# Can not open draw9patch.bat normally

Tags: android

i installed the newest version of Android SDK,and use SDK Tool Revision 20.0.3, and then i double click the 'draw9patch.bat',i hope it can show me an UI,unfortunately, the bat file just run flashing past, does not show the UI. And then i try to double click 'hierarchyviewer.bat', the program doesn't show an UI either. I don't know why and i can get the ways to solve this problem from the Internet, so i turn to your guys for help.

Comment: read about execute .bat file from cmd

Comment: If you run it from the command prompt, you'll be able to see the error it's giving instead of it automatically closing the window.

Comment: I then go to the path of draw9patch.bat in the command window, input 'draw9patch.bat' and press 'Enter', it does not show the graphic UI of draw9patch tool, nor show the error log.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you set environment path for java . Open command prompt and navigate to android-sdk\tools\lib folder and type **java -jar draw9patch.jar** press enter . now you could get see UI screen if  no problem with this .jar file .

Comment: Thanks to Nagarajan, the way works. Still, it is uncomfortable to use draw9patch tool by your way, can i fix the problem by another way?

Comment: You can create your own .bat file and use 9patch . Go to android-sdk\tools directory and create a file called my9patch.bat (any file name with extension .bat ) right click on that file and choose edit . then paste this command **java -jar %~dp0\lib\draw9patch.jar** save and close that file . now you can access this file by typing my9patch in cmd or  double click on my9patch .

Comment: hi，Nagarajan! Sorry for bothering you again.Where should I insert the command **java -jar %~dp0\lib\draw9patch.jar** into the content of draw9patch.bat.@Nagarajan

Comment: you need to create a new .bat file in android-sdk\tools directory and type above commands

Answer (score 0):

Probably, "find_java.bat" and it's associated crap exe are failing miserably at doing the one thing it's supposed to do. I don't know how it's supposed to work or why it's failing, and I don't really care. Java is installed and this exe is a failure - so purge the damn dependency and be done with it. Who knows, maybe find_java.exe is some damn NSA virus - never worked for me before (maybe it can't find 64-bit Java... worthless rubbish).

Ahem, yeah, anyway...

Go to draw9patch.bat and change these three lines:

```
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

to this (use your Java path):

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe
```

Then you should even be able to run draw9patch.bat with another bat file wherever you want to place it for convenience, by doing something like this inside the new bat:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\draw9patch.bat"
```

No idea why this 'answer' wasn't here a year ago. Open a command prompt... please. :P